# Akka actor throws null pointer error, reason unknown

Tags: scala, null, akka, actor

I have a rest controller which calls a service, which in turn calls an actor to get a query from a simulated database. The message makes its way to the actor, but the app crashes before the actor can respond, and there is a null pointer exception coming from the actor. I'm using akka http for the controller and routing directives to compose the response. These are my dependencies:

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http"   % "10.1.8",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor"  % "2.5.22",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.22",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.1.8"




class CacheActor extends Actor {

  val tweetRepositoryInMemory: TweetRepositoryInMemory = new TweetRepositoryInMemory()
  val log = Logging(context.system, this)

  var tweetMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]] =
    scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, List[String]]()

  // consult the in-memory map, if the username is not found, call the repository, update  the map, and return the tweets
  def queryRepo(username: String): Future[Option[List[String]]] = {
    if (tweetMap isDefinedAt username) {

      return Future(tweetMap.get(username))
    } else {
      var listOfTweetTexts: List[String] = List[String]()

      val queryLimit = 10

      val resultTweets: Future[Seq[Tweet]] = tweetRepositoryInMemory.searchByUserName(username, queryLimit)

      onComplete(resultTweets) {
        case Success(tweets) =>
          for (tweet <- tweets) { listOfTweetTexts ::= tweet.text; }

          tweetMap(username) = listOfTweetTexts

          return Future(Option(listOfTweetTexts))

        case Failure(t) =>
          log.error("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
          return null
      }
    }
    return null
  }

  def receive = {

    case message: TweetQuery => // .take(message.limit)

      val queryResult: Future[Option[List[String]]] = queryRepo(message.userName)

      queryResult onComplete {
        case Success(result) => sender() ! result

        case Failure(t) => log.error("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stacktrace would have been helpful, but I suspect that this line here in your `receive` causes the NPE:

```
queryResult onComplete {
```

Your `queryRepo` function returns `null` if `tweetMap` is not defined at `username`.

**UPDATE**

And here is why:

The `queryRepo` function returns a `Furture[Seq[String]]` in exactly one case

```
if (tweetMap isDefinedAt username) {
  return Future(tweetMap.get(username))
}
```

In the else block you create a `Future[Seq[String]]`

```
val resultTweets: Future[Seq[String]] = tweetRepositoryInMemory.searchByUserName(username, queryLimit)
```

but you never return that. **Instead** you pass a callback to the Future that is executed asynchronously when the futures completes, hence `onComplete`. (I noticed that you do not call `onComplete` on the `Future` directly but a function `onComplete` that takes the future and a partial function as an argument and I am assuming that that function registers the regular `onComplete` callback.)

Thus the result of the else block of your if statement is `Unit` and **not** `Future[Seq[String]]`

The code

```
 for (tweet <- tweets) { listOfTweetTexts ::= tweet.text; }

 tweetMap(username) = listOfTweetTexts

 return Future(Option(listOfTweetTexts))
```

is most likely executed after `queryRepo` has already returned `null`.

```
def queryRepo(username: String): Future[Option[List[String]]] = {
  if (tweetMap isDefinedAt username) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
  return null // <--- here
}
```

**End UPDATE**

If you change the following lines:

```
val resultTweets: Future[Seq[Tweet]] = tweetRepositoryInMemory.searchByUserName(username, queryLimit)

  onComplete(resultTweets) {
    case Success(tweets) =>
      for (tweet <- tweets) { listOfTweetTexts ::= tweet.text; }

      tweetMap(username) = listOfTweetTexts

      return Future(Option(listOfTweetTexts))

    case Failure(t) =>
      log.error("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
      return null
  }
```

to:

```
tweetRepositoryInMemory.searchByUserName(username, queryLimit).map { tweets =>
  // NOTE: This happens asynchronously in the `Future`. IT is better not to close over local variables  
  val listOfTweetTexts = for (tweet <- tweets) yield { tweet.text }
  // again, access to an actor member from within a `Future` is not wise or rather a bug in the making. 
  // But I will not refactor that much here. The way to do this would be to send a message to self and process the mutable member within `receive`
  tweetMap(username) = listOfTweetTexts
  Option(listOfTweetTexts)
}
```

The `NullPointerException` should no longer occur.

However, my impression is that you could use some more training with *futures*, *actors* and *functional programming* in scala in general.

For example,

- mutable local state of an Actor does only work if accessed from within its `receive` and not in an asynchronous `Future` or `Thread`
- one ususally does not use the return keyword in scala
- if not for java api interoperability, there is no need to **ever** return `null`.
- and many more points ...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Sacha, I definitely could. What do you mean by your first point though? I'm calling the queryRepo method from within receive. query repo returns a future but receive eventually returns the result of that future. Is there something I missed?. Also, if you could elaborate on the "many other points" it would be very useful.

Comment: @Boris I update my answer and I hope that it is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks Sacha, that's very informative. I just have a couple doubts about your notes: What do you mean by 'it is better not to close over local variables'? Do you mean it's better not to mutate local variables in a callback? Also, what's the difference between yield, map, and onComplete(future) when processing futures?

Comment: 1. to close over means that the lambda aka. closure you captures variable form the context it is created in. Please read documentation about lambdas and closures in scala.

Comment: 2. to mutate local variables (variable in a very limited scope) is not that dangerous in your specific usecase as you only mutate it within the asynchous future and use it as result of the future. However, you have to be aware of the fact that a future runs in a different thread and concurrent writes from two different thread is dangerous, isn't it?

Comment: `for (tweet <- tweets) yield { tweet.text }` is a for-comprehension. In this case it creates a sesquence of `String` from a sequence of `Tweet`. It is equivalent to `tweets.map(tweet => tweet.text)` (if you are more familiar with `map`.

Comment: Ok I think i understand you now, but in this case I have an actor that acts as a DAO, it queries the database and sends a message to the sender. I'm left with the following question: What is the most efficient way to execute code within an actor such as in my example? If you fire off a couple of futures within an actor, you have to wait until you have their result before you repy to the sender, so what's the differene between calling onComplete, and Await? What thread is the result of the future processed on in those two cases, and which is better?

Comment: Akka offers the pipeTo pattern for that use case. You need to  `import akka.pattern.pipe` and then you can do somehting like `Future { ...; return tweets } map { tweets.map(_.text) } pipeTo sender()`

Comment: is there a difference in terms of performance and thread saftey between calling onComplete and calling pipeTO?